# Struct Problems for Pushdown Automata

Tags: c, struct, pushdown-automaton

I think my struct knowledge is lacking.  I am getting errors such as:

> 1. pda.c:33:26: error: 'top' undeclared (first use in this function)
>               if(pda.stack[top] == '\0')
> 2. pda.c:54:7: error: 'accepted' undeclared (first use in this function)
>      if(accepted == 0)
> 3. pda.c: In function 'qX':
>      pda.c:93:17: error: 'top' undeclared (first use in this function)
>      pda.stack[top] = input;

Basically the variables in my global struct are not being recognized, and I'm not sure why.  Here is my documented code:

```
//This project is a PDA which accepts alphabetical, lower-case palindromes written out and divided by a #.
//Example: "hello world#dlrow olleh" is an accepted string.
#include <stdio.h>
//Pushdown automata structure includes the string to validate with an index, the stack
//with an index, the current state, the running status, and the result.
struct PDA {
   char string[200];
   char stack[200];
   int current;
   int top;
   int qOrp;
   int finished;
   int accepted;
};
//Initialization of struct and state methods.
struct PDA pda = {.current = 0, .top = 0, .qOrp = 0, .finished = 0, .accepted = 0};
int validateInput();
int qE(char input);
int qX(char input);
int pX(char input);
int pE();

int main() {
   //Prompt for string to validate.
   printf("Enter the string to be verified: ");
   scanf("%s\n", &pda.string);
   //Validates the alphabet of the string.
   pda.finished = validateInput();
   //While the PDA is rinning, do...
   while(pda.finished == 0) {
      //Different cases for different states.
      switch(pda.qOrp) {
         case 0:
            //State for the initial, empty stack.
            if(pda.stack[top] == '\0')
               pda.finished = qE(pda.string[current]);
            //State for non-empty stack before the #.
            else {
               pda.finished = qE(pda.string[current]);
            }
            break;
         case 1:
            //State for empty stack after #.
            if(pda.stack[top] == '\0')
               pda.finished = pE();
            //State for non-empty stack after #.
            else
               pda.finished = pX(pda.string[current]);
            break;
         //Reject if not in one of the states above.
         default:
            pda.finished = 1;
      }
   }
   //Print for acceptance/rejection.
   if(accepted == 0)
      printf("The string \"%s\" is rejected.", pda.string);
   else
      printf("The string \"%s\" is accepted.", pda.string);

   return 0;
}
//Loops through the string to validate and makes sure the alphabet is correct.  Otherwise, reject.
int validateInput() {
   int i = 0;

   while(pda.string[i] != '\0') {
      if(pda.string[i] < 97 || pda.string[i] > 122 || pda.string[i] != '#' || pda.string[i] != ' ')
         return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
//Initial State.  Checks for illegal characters.  Otherwise, push current character.
int qE(char input) {
   if(input == '#')
      return 1;
   else {
      pda.stack[top] = input;
      pda.top++;
      pda.current++;
      return 0;
   }   
}
//Second State.  Switches to next state on #.  Otherwise, push current character.
int qX(char input) {
   if(input == '#') {
      pda.qOrp++;
      pda.current--;
      pda.top--;
   }
   else {
      pda.stack[top] = input;
      pda.top++;
      pda.current++;
   }
}
//Third state.  Checks for illegal characters.  Otherwise, pop one element from stack.
int pX(char input) {   
   if(input == '#')
      return 1;
   else {
      if(pda.string[current] == pda.stack[top]) {
         pda.stack[top] = '\0';
         pda.top--;
         pda.current--;
      }
      else
         return 1;
   }
}
//Final state.  Declares the string "accepted."
int pE() {
   pda.accepted = 1;
   return 1;  
}
```

Any Ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the other variables in the struct, `top` must be accessed as `pda.top` using the dot notation. And `accepted` must be `pda.accepted`.

Some languages have a name scoping operator like `with` or `using`, but C doesn't have a shortcut for this.